# py2app and Pyside2 5.15 Failure

Tags: python, qt, pyside2, py2app

I have created a basic py2app 0.21 setup for use with PySide2 Qt 5.15.0 in Python 3.8.2 and the find product fails to include the full and correct Qt dylibs and resources required to run.

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['demo.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {}


setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app']
)
```

with a demo python `demo.py` that looks like

```
import os
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickView
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QUrl


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    view =  QQuickView()
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView.SizeRootObjectToView)

    qml_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),  'view.qml')

    view.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(os.path.abspath(qml_file)))

    if view.status() == QQuickView.Error:
        sys.exit(-1)

    view.show()
    app.exec_()

    del view
```

running `python demo.py py2app` and creating the .app works fine and alias mode runs, but regular mode crashes. Running the script manually from console with gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo/python/basic_qml/dist/demo.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 101, in <module>
    _run()
  File "demo/python/basic_qml/dist/demo.app/Contents/Resources/__boot__.py", line 84, in _run
    exec(compile(source, path, "exec"), globals(), globals())
  File "demo/python/basic_qml/dist/demo.app/Contents/Resources/demo.py", line 7, in <module>
    from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "PySide2/__init__.pyc", line 88, in <module>
  File "PySide2/__init__.pyc", line 54, in _setupQtDirectories
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "shiboken2/__init__.pyc", line 27, in <module>
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
  File "shiboken2/shiboken2.pyc", line 14, in <module>
  File "shiboken2/shiboken2.pyc", line 10, in __load
  File "imp.pyc", line 342, in load_dynamic
ImportError: dlopen(demo/python/basic_qml/dist/demo.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/shiboken2/shiboken2.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libshiboken2.abi3.5.15.dylib
  Referenced from: demo/python/basic_qml/dist/demo.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/shiboken2/shiboken2.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I tried

1. Adding the dylib for shiboken2 manually. I noticed that this dylib is in the build directory but is not in the dist package. That led to the same message for `libpyside2.abi3.5.15.dylib` which I also added and this led to a series of frameworks for QtCore, QtQML, QtNetworking. After adding all these into the pyside2 library of the distribution package, I got a generic "failed import" on QtCore in python.
2. Playing with includes or packages but no luck yet
3. Adding `from PySide2 import shiboken2` but this fixed nothing

Is py2app 0.21 and Qt 5.15 currently compatible and what combination of includes and packages does it require?